# Error while migrating persistent store

Tags: macos, sqlite, cocoa, core-data

In my Document-based app i've faced some problems with migrating persistent store from in-app Documents folder to somewhere else in current user's chosen folder.

(code is simplified)

I init managed object context like this

```
_moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
[_moc setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
[_moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
[_moc setUndoManager:[self undoManager]];
```

I use these persistent store options

```
NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
NSSQLitePragmasOption =     {
    "journal_mode" = DELETE;
};
```

And create

```
store = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:absoluteURL options:[options copy] error:error];
```

And location of this persistent store is
   file:///Users/currentuser/Library/Containers/com.my.application.osx/Data/Documents/doc1.ext

Then I fill up some preferences

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
[[managedObjectContext undoManager] disableUndoRegistration];

NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = description;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

Settings *file = nil;

if (error == nil) {
    if ([results count]>0) {
        file = [results firstObject];
    } else {
        file = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];

    }
    [Settings setEntityFromUserDefaults:&file];
}
_fileSettings = file;
[managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
[[managedObjectContext undoManager] enableUndoRegistration];
[self syncFileModificationDate];
```

And finally, when I try to perform this operation

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator];
[coordinator migratePersistentStore:[coordinator.persistentStores firstObject] toURL:absoluteURL options:[coordinator.persistentStores firstObject].options withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error2];
```

I what I see in debug console

> 2017-04-11 18:09:32.336 Project [36495:4118531] CoreData:
>   error: (21) I/O error for database at /Users/dzawadsky/Documents/tmp
>   author docs/doc1.ext.  SQLite error code:21, 'unable to open
>   database file'
>
> 2017-04-11 18:24:42.980 Project [36495:4118531] CoreData: error: -
>   -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:PF_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_NAME
>   URL:file:///Users/dzawadsky/Documents/tmp%20author%20docs/doc1.ext
>   options:{
>
> ```
> NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
>
> NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
>
> NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption = 1;
>
> NSSQLitePragmasOption =     {
>     "journal_mode" = DELETE;
> };
> ```
>
> } ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=21 "(null)"
>
> UserInfo={NSSQLiteErrorDomain=21, NSUnderlyingException=I/O
>   error for database at /Users/currentuser/Documents/tmp author
>   docs/doc1.ext.  SQLite error code:21, 'unable to open database
>   file'} with userInfo dictionary {
>
> ```
> NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 21;
>
> NSUnderlyingException = "I/O error for database at /Users/currentuser/Documents/tmp author docs/doc1.ext.  SQLite error
> ```
>
> code:21, 'unable to open database file'";
>
> }

**UPD**

I've already tried to go another way -

```
[fileManager copyItemAtURL:itemAtURL toURL:absoluteURL error:&error2];
```

and set

```
[super setFileURL:absoluteURL];
```

So managed object context's persistent store has been changed, but when I add some managed objects to context and call

```
[_moc save:&error];
```

Error repeats - it's still the same error as I've mentioned before

Comment: Since you're writing for Macs, is it sandbox-related maybe? As in, your app isn't allowed to save files in the target directory?

Comment: @TomHarrington My bad, sure thing I have enabled read/write access to user selected files etc

Comment: So any suggestions? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though question is quite old,
I've tried to check everything which wants to be saved in CoreData. It's appear that at some point, while spamming undo action, system wants to save object with garbage fields (but I have only one constructor for this object, that prevents creating such fields' values). Tried to detect place where this object creates, unsuccessfully. So, I prevent writing of this garbage object. I've done it as far as I remember using some kind of resetPending selector of ManagedObjectContext, or smth like that (not exactly -[moc reset], it'll clear all data in your MOC, be careful)!